# C++ best way to switch between configs

Tags: c++

I have some code that I need to run for separate cases. I would have to switch mostly some enums and statics for those cases. So, let's say I have enums

```
enum class City { NY, LA, W_DC, ... }
City capital = City::W_DC
```

and for the other case

```
enum class City { LDN, BMH, EDB, ... }
City capital = City::LDN
```

Assuming I have a lot of those enums, what is the best way to reuse most of the code and switch between those configuration. To be clear, this is not meant to happen during runtime, the program is supposed to compile for one case and be oblivious about anything else.

EDIT: following StackOverflowUser to use macros

would it be a good approach to store the different enum configs in different namespaces and then do

```
#IFDEF USE_NAMESPACE_A
    using namespace namespace_a
#ELSE
    using namespace namespace_a
#ENDIF
```

Comment: Why not combine the enums?

Comment: That wouldnt help me with variables like capital in the example

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `City capital` can easily contain values for `City::W_DC` or `City::LDN` if they are in the same enum.

Comment: yes, but I would then still need to set capital based on whether I want to run A or B. There is a lot of static variables that are set differently in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Creating macros and using `#ifdef MACRONAME` is the best way to check things before run time, in my opinion.
You can also create `constexpr` variables and use ifs to evaluate those variables' values. Since the variables are `constexpr`, the compiler would most likely optimize them away.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create separate source files, each containing the enum you want.  You then make different compile targets that compile the relevant file as part of the build.

Another option is to use the #ifdef...#else preprocessor macros as stated previously, but you'll likely have different compile targets to define the macro that includes the correct file.  Rather than set it up so you have to change code AND change the build, just put it in the build.

But, honestly, enums are probably not the best way to do what you're wanting to do.  A lookup from a file/database/or some other datasource at runtime would likely be a more maintainable approach.  It requires a bit more work obviously, but if this is something to maintain long-term you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Compile target is actually the same. wouldnt any lookup at runtime generally be slower? I would prefer to be able to break this up on compile time to avoid extra overhead in functions

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be slower.  If you had a gigabyte worth of unindexed data to iterate, sure it would be slower.  It all depends on your implementation really.  If your compile target is the same, you have to figure out how to pass in the defined value used in the #ifdef in some way.